# These assets are not style sheets error in BundleTransformer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, bundle

I encountered this annoying error telling me that .less files are not stylesheets. Oh Yea.

> BundleTransformer.Core.Validators.InvalidAssetTypesException :  These
>   assets are not style sheets :
>   'Site/Content/Stylesheets/Less/style.less'

I have BundleTransformer.Less  ( as package ).

My BundleConfig.cs :

```
bundles.Add(new LessStyleBundle("~/SiteCSS").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/Stylesheets/Less", "*.less"));
```

My LessStyleBundle class :

```
 public sealed class LessStyleBundle : StyleBundle
    {

        private static readonly IBundleTransform _cssTransformer = new StyleTransformer();
        private static readonly IBundleTransform _cssMinify = new CssMinify();

        public LessStyleBundle(string virtualPath)
            : base(virtualPath)
        {
            Orderer = new NullOrderer();
            Transforms.Add(_cssTransformer);
            Transforms.Add(_cssMinify);
        }
    }
```

And layout rendering :

```
@Styles.Render("~/SiteCSS")
```

Anyone encounter same problem ? Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: in release mode has it same error?

Comment: Yes. Same error in release & debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your the `Web.config` file. There should be the following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
        <core ...>
            <css ...>
                ...
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
                    <add fileExtension=".less" assetTypeCode="Less" />
                    ...
                </fileExtensions>
                ...
            </css>
            ...
        </core>
    </bundleTransformer>
</configuration>
```

Also I do not recommend to write your own `LessStyleBundle` class. Better to use the `BundleTransformer.Core.Bundles.CustomStyleBundle` class and install the [BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax/) module (after installation please read the `readme.txt` file).

Comment: I've used the custom style bundle class for one month and everything worked smooth, but forgot to answer this question. Thanks a lot, useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Install nuget package BundleTransformer.Less. It will resolve the issue.

check package.config